# Hive SerDe - One Record per File for External Tables

Tags: hive

How can we specify one record per file when creating external tables.
The data i have is of this format. one row per file and the format of the row is 
compressed_ bytebuffer(jackson.write(java pojo))

So how do we specify that Hive should treat the content in the file as one Record and pass it to my SerDe.
I took a look in to the code of JSonSerde and looks like if i can get the entire blob to my SeDe serialize/deserialize methods then i just have to uncompress and the rest of JSonSerDe code will work fine for my case. Any suggestions/ideas on whether this approach will work?

Answer (score 0):

Not to say you can't do this, but you're going against the grain of Hadoop. Don't think of things as a 1-file-to-1-input. Instead, load all of your input with some sort of record delimiter (normally a \n). Then let Hadoop drive.

As for the SerDe, Hive will read the record based on the delimiter of the source data. This means that the blob will be (should be) your compressed JSON. So start by extending the JSON SerDe. First you'd have to uncompress it, then just hand it to super of the JSON SerDe.

Again, you feel like you're going against the system architecture. Let Hive manage the compression for you. Load the data uncompressed and let the sub system manage compression by setting things like Snappy or LZO. This provides you options like block compression or recompression.